# use eloquent whereRaw($query) if $query not null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i wanna use `whereRaw()` in laravel app. 
can i use laravel eloquent `whereRaw($query)`  just when `$query` has exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what exactly you want to achieve because you haven't showed a piece of code but you could use:

```
$yourQuery->when($query, function($q) use ($query) {
   $q->whereRaw($query);
});
```

of course you can also use condition:

```
if ($query) {
  $yourQuery->whereRaw($query);
}
```